# Specializing behavior of describe method, as explained by Sonya E. Keene

Tags: common-lisp, clos, describe

In the book **Object Oriented Programming in COMMON LISP** by S. Keene, she introduces specializing the behavior of the `describe` generic function by providing an `:after` method for some classes, but this will result in an error in SBCL and Clozure:

```
COMMON-LISP:DESCRIBE already names an ordinary function or a
macro. [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

This happens when i try to modify the behavior of `describe` for my class:

```
(defclass klasse ()
  ())

(defmethod describe :after ((obj klasse))
  (print "Klasse!"))
```

As the book is from 1989, are these locking policies something which has happened after the release of the book, or am i missing something else?

Comment: as far as i know, the book describes the language of a before ANSI standartization era (standartization happened in 1994). In ansi cl `describe` is indeed on ordinary function, while there is a generic one, named `describe-object`. That one should fit, i guess

Comment: clhs says the following: The actual act of describing the object is implemented by describe-object. describe exists as an interface primarily to manage argument defaulting (including conversion of arguments t and nil into stream objects) and to inhibit any return values from describe-object.

Comment: so you specify `(defmethod describe-object :after ((obj klasse) stm) (print "Klasse!" stm))` and call it with `describe`: `(describe (make-instance 'klasse))`. that will do the trick

Comment: @leetwinski: you may want to write an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, the book describes the language of a before ANSI standartization era (standartization happened in 1994). 
In ansi cl `describe` is indeed on ordinary function, while there is a generic one, named `describe-object`

CLHS says the following on [this subject](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_descri.htm):

> The actual act of describing the object is implemented by describe-object. describe exists as an interface primarily to manage argument defaulting (including conversion of arguments t and nil into stream objects) and to inhibit any return values from describe-object.

So, what you need to do, is to specify

```
(defmethod describe-object :after ((obj klasse) stm) 
    (print "Klasse!" stm))
```

and call it with describe:

```
CL-USER> (describe (make-instance 'klasse))
;;=> #<KLASSE {1001C3C1F3}>
;;     [standard-object]
;;   No slots.

;;   "Klasse!" 
;;   ; No values
```